# how i get the json body in controller in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, json

```
    <?php
 namespace VEndor\Module\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {    protected $resultPageFactory;    public function __construct(
           \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
           \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
       {
           $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
           parent::__construct($context);
       }    public function execute()    {                                $curl = curl_init();
                                    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
                                        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                                    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://tgrestcURL.com/?item1=value&item2=value2',
                                    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
                                ));
                                // Send the request & save response to $resp
                                $resp = curl_exec($curl);
                                // Close request to clear up some resources
                                curl_close($curl);
       }
    }
```

Comment: where this json data coming from to the controller.Just explain flow

Comment: thanx for reply this json data coming from api

Comment: you are calling this API from controller right?using curl you can achieve it

Comment: yes can you tell me please how i get this json body in controller in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Once you've compiled PHP with cURL support, you can begin using the cURL functions. The basic idea behind the cURL functions is that you initialize a cURL session using the curl_init(), then you can set all your options for the transfer via the curl_setopt(), then you can execute the session with the curl_exec() and then you finish off your session using the curl_close(). Here is an example that uses the cURL functions to fetch the example.com homepage into a file

we can use CURL functionality in magento like we use in php.write below code in magento controller and set the required options in CURL as your API requires.

```
/ Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://testcURL.com/?item1=value&item2=value2',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: great thanks for reply can yoyu tell me  how i implement this  code in controller

Comment: Controller is simple .PHP file .paste tis code in execute() mehod

Comment: yes i did but not work for me

Comment: post your full controller code in question

Answer (score 0):

**Inject json factory class:**

`\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory` to `__construct` function

**On convert `resp` is  to `array` from `Json` if `$resp` is `json` variable .**

=====================================

```
<?php
namespace VEndor\Module\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $jsonFactory;    
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
            )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;       
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $jsonFactory =  $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $curl = curl_init();
        // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://tgrestcURL.com/?item1=value&item2=value2',
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
        ));
        // Send the request & save response to $resp
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        // Close request to clear up some resources
        curl_close($curl);
    }
    /* to Convert JSON to array */
    $resp = json_decode($resp);
    return $jsonFactory->setData($finalrespose);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work it returns null. However if you remove the `json_decode` it return e.g `"Array\n(\n    [0] => Array\n        (\n            [country] => (not set)\n `